# How is multiplication defined on Grassman ring?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Kenneth Hoffman's "Linear Algebra", Ed 2. In $\S5.7$ "the Grassman Ring" it briefly mentioned:

> The exterior product defines a multiplication product on forms and
>   extend it linearly to $\Lambda(V)$. It distributes over the addition of
>   $\Lambda(V)$ and gives $\Lambda(V)$ the structure of a ring. This ring
>   is the Grassman ring over $V^*$. It is not a commutative ring...

But I still wonder how is it defined? Is there an explicit definition on the Grassman ring multiplication I could read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Lambda(V)= \oplus_{k=1}^{\infty}\Lambda^k(V)$ and use multiplication map as $\Lambda^k(V) \times \Lambda^l(V) \rightarrow \Lambda^{k+l}(V)$ so this induces multiplication on $\Lambda(V)$.